# Use css subgrid with automatic column spans

Tags: css, css-grid, subgrid

I have the following html structure.

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="achild1">Child 1</div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-column: span 6; /* <-- span is not known prior to runtime. crux of the QUESTION */
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grandparent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); /* 12 columns */
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 20px;
}

.achild1 {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.achild2 {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

to achieve the following effect

[image: Intended Effect]

The problem is that the number of `achild2` is dynamic and each of these may span variable number of columns. So a `parent` **SPAN** cannot be specified.

I can use `display: contents` on the `parent` and it works well. I was wondering how to achieve the same effect using **SUBGRID**

A codepen link to experiment with:
https://codepen.io/rsun2100/pen/GRebbvJ

Comment: For what reasons do you not know the number of elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of CSS Grid and Flexbox.

```
.grandparent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 20px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.achild1 {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Dynamically set the width of child1 */
  width: calc(50% - 5px); /* Subtracting margin and gap */
}

.achild2 {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="achild1">Child 1</div>
    <!-- Dynamic generation of achild2 elements -->
  </div>
  <!-- Separate .achild1 outside of .parent -->
  <div class="achild1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work: see the forked codepen: https://codepen.io/rsun2100/pen/gOENNBM; the parent is now restricted to 1 column

Comment: check the edited code now :)

Comment: no the parent still occupies a single column of the grid - so all the `achild2` are in the same column. In the desired result, all the `achild2` are in the same row. Furthermore we don't know the number of children till runtime. The `achild1` cannot be a child of the parent

Comment: okay, I guess this should work, check the answer now, I've updated whole answer

Answer (score 0):

One posibility is to use the new :has selector, to target .parent based on how many children it has.

You will need to set as many styles as posible number of elements. In the snippet, only the styles for 4 and 6 children are present:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-column: span 1; 
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent:has(div:nth-child(4)) {
    grid-column: span 4; 
}

.parent:has(div:nth-child(6)) {
    grid-column: span 6; 
}

.grandparent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); /* 12 columns */
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 20px;
}

.achild1 {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.achild2 {
  background-color: #41974e;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="achild1">Child 1</div>
</div>
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
    <div class="achild2">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="achild1">Child 1</div>
</div>
```